# Why do I have to pass a callable to re.sub to make an uppercase string?

Tags: python, regex, string

Below is a somewhat contrived example that get's at my eventual question...

I would like to use regex to uppercase the first character of a possessive noun. Let's say that I have a regular expression that (probably poorly) matches possessive nouns. ie...

```
### Regex explanation ###
# 1. match a word break
# 2. match a word-like character and capture in a group
# 3. lookahead for some more characters + the substring "'s"

>>> my_re = re.compile(r"\b(\w)(?=\w+'s)")
>>> re.search(my_re, "bruce's computer")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='b'>

>>> re.search(my_re, "bruce's computer").group(1)
'b'
```

For this example, it works as expected. So, I think that all have to do is call upper on the first group in sub and it should work, right?

```
>>> re.sub(my_re, r'\1'.upper(), "bruce's computer")
"bruce's computer"
```

This is not expected or obvious why it is not capital. After some research I find this in the re.sub documentation...

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping
>   occurrences of the pattern in string by the replacement repl. repl can
>   be either a string or a callable; if a string, backslash escapes in it
>   are processed. **If it is a callable, it's passed the match object and
>   must return a replacement string to be used.**

Indeed passing a callable does work...

```
>>> re.sub(my_re, lambda x: x.group(1).upper(), "bruce's computer")
"Bruce's computer"
```

Great. What I would like to understand is why does this work otherwise I won't remember how use the API correctly for this type of instance without looking it up. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Arguments are evaluated before the `sub` function is called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Second argument can be string or a callable.

`re.sub(my_re, r'\1'.upper(), "bruce's computer")`: you're passing a `\1` *string* to the `sub` function (upper or not, doesn't matter)

`re.sub(my_re, lambda x: x.group(1).upper(), "bruce's computer")`: you're passing a *callable*, so the `upper()` works because it applies on the result.

`x.group(1).upper()` isn't evaluated at once because it's contained in a lambda expression, equivalent to the non-lambda:

```
def func(x):
   return x.group(1).upper()
```

that you could also pass to `re.sub`: `re.sub(my_re, func, "bruce's computer")`, note the lack of `()` in that case!