# replacing a template string using the matched pattern as an index into a dict

Tags: python

I am trying to replace a template string with values that are available in another dict. I am aware of how to do this using `.findall` and then `.replace` but I was trying to convert it to one operation.

This is what I tried:

```
import re
p = r'{{(\w+?)}}'
g = {'call':'CALL', 'ball':'BALL'}
s = 'This was the day I would {{call}} and play {{ball}} with my {{dog}}'

a = re.sub(p, g.get('{}'.format(r'\1'),'NONE'), s)
print(a)
```

I expected:

```
This was the day I would CALL and play BALL with my NONE
```

But I got:

```
This was the day I would NONE and play NONE with my NONE
```

Can we not use matched strings `\1` like I did?

**Edited: larger problem statement:** (to address Hagai's note)

Given a string with "placeholders", replace their values from a dict.
Example:

```
'Dear {{FirstName}} your {{Vehicle}} has been impounded. Please call {{TowingService}} for more details. Thanks for reading, {{FirstName}}!'
```

Where

```
dict = { 'AcctId':921103,
         'FirstName': 'Buzz', 
         'LastName': 'LightYear',
         'Address': 'Milkyway',
         'TowingService': 'Darknot',
         'Vehicle': 'Mazda'
}
```

In other words, we don't know which template variables will be used and it what order, and how many times they will be repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without any further explaination why you need to use regex, it seem to me like a big overkill.
use built-in `str` method `str.format`.
that code would look like:

```
s.format(**g)
```

if you also have some placeholders which you want a default value to them (such as dog -> NONE) then use regex to find all of them and then add them all to a default dict.
that would look like:

```
pattern = "{(.*?)}"
found = re.findall(pattern, s)
for fill in found:
   g[fill] = "NONE"

s.format(**g)
```

UPDATE:
personally i prefer using re package the least i can since it's execution is almost always longer especially for longer strings.
saw your answer tho and liked it so upvote

Expended question UPDATE:
if you are using python 3.2+ the simplest solution would be to use [`str.format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map).
it goes like that:

```
class Formatter(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return "Oh no!"

"an {a} with some {b} and a {c}".format_map(Formatter(a="eagle", b="fish"))

>>> "and eagle with some fish and a Oh no!"
```

note that:

1. in this simple solution no need to unpack Formatter class (which is basically a dict with a `__missing__` method)
2. you can wrap your existing dict with that Formatter class inline so you don't really need to change existing code: `Formatter(existing_dict)` would work perfectly
3. if you are forced to act with double curly parenthesis (`{{some-string}}`) then you can chain the method. like:

```
"an {{a}} with some {{b}} and a {{c}}"
    .format_map(Formatter(a="eagle", b="fish"))
    .format_map(Formatter(a="eagle", b="fish"))
```

---

if under python 3.2 then i'de suggest using the answer that i first wrote as it will find and update if there are some parameters that are in the string and not in the dict (which would cause `KeyError`).  for the situation where your dict has more than what the string needs, that OK you don't need to do anything, `str.format` would simply ignore it gracfully

Comment: I could swear I left a comment, but don't see it. Here goes again: Thanks - I'd love to avoid regexp too, but not sure if its possible to use `s.format(*g)` here - I've expanded the context in my original question. If you think it is still possible to avoid regexp, I'll go with that for sure! Thanks!

Comment: posted and update!  
btw i think you replied accidentally to your own answer :P

Comment: This is very nice. Just tried it out. There is so much inbuilt functionality in python that is just waiting to be discovered. I wonder if it is possible for us to do some magic and replace the {} with {{}} in string matching without using another pattern replacement? I'm working with a template that happens to use {{param}} instead of {param}

Comment: i see, looks like Angular is forcing you badly, thats OK, just run the method twice... kinda sad but it works. ill update asnwer

Answer (score 1):

Ah, thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622102/why-do-i-have-to-pass-a-callable-to-re-sub-to-make-an-uppercase-string), looks like when `r'\1'` is used this way, it is passed as a string.

Reworking it this way works as intended:

```
import re
p = r'{{(\w+?)}}'
g = {'call':'CALL', 'ball':'BALL'}
s = 'This was the day I would {{call}} and play {{ball}} with my {{dog}}'
a = re.sub(p, lambda m: g.get(m.group(1), 'NONE'), s)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
This was the day I would CALL and play BALL with my NONE
```

Comment: Thank you. I added more context. I'd love to avoid regexp as well, but I'm not sure it is possible given the context I added?