# Replace matched susbtring using re sub

Tags: python-3.x, regex, substring

Is there a way to replace the matched pattern substring using a single `re.sub()` line?.
What I would like to avoid is using a string replace method to the current `re.sub()` output.

```
Input =  "/J&L/LK/Tac1_1/shareloc.pdf"

Current output using re.sub("[^0-9_]", "", input): "1_1"

Desired output in a single re.sub use: "1.1"
```

Comment: What is the logic? Can you provide more examples, like with more than one match, other characters between digits, ...etc.

Comment: The input is pretty much the same for most of my cases. The logic would be to extract all the numbers and once the matched pattern: 1_1 is found replace the "_" by "." Another example could be "/J&L/LK/Tac219_4\shareloc.pdf" and the expected output would be 219.4

Comment: What if your input string has multiple such numbers? Like `"hello 1_2 world 3_4!"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is defined as

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

> If `repl` is a **function**, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern.

This said, if you pass a lambda function, you can remain the code in one line. Furthermore, remember that the matched characters can be accessed easier to an individual group by: `x[0]`.

I removed `_` from the regex to reach the desired output.

```py
txt = "/J&L/LK/Tac1_1/shareloc.pdf"
x = re.sub("[^0-9]", lambda x: '.' if x[0] is '_' else '', txt)
print(x)
```

Comment: This would keep and replace *any* underscore, not just those that happen to separate digits.

Comment: Then the regex should be adapted to match this exact behavior

Comment: As @trincot notice this will replace for all the underscores which is not desireable. E.g: for the case "'F::\\JK\\DL\\DFIC222_1_ref_Count\x0cileloc.pdf'" the output will be 221.1..and should be 221.1

Comment: Maybe using ([^0-9]+) can capture the behaviour...I did some tests and seems to work. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use a string replacement pattern in Python `re.sub` to replace with two possible strings, as there is no conditional replacement construct support in Python `re.sub`. So, [using a callable as the replacement argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622102/why-do-i-have-to-pass-a-callable-to-re-sub-to-make-an-uppercase-string) or use other work-arounds.

It looks like you only expect one match of `<DIGITS>_<DIGITS>` in the input string. In this case, you can use

```py
import re
text = "/J&L/LK/Tac1_1/shareloc.pdf"
print( re.sub(r'^.*?(\d+)_(\d+).*', r'\1.\2', text, flags=re.S) )
# => 1.1
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/cjQIGv). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PHyK55/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `_` - a `_` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `.*` - zero or more chars as many as possible.